# How to reset password with django rest framework SessionAuthentication

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework, session-cookies, httpie

I'm building an api for a mobile app. The mobile client has full support for cookies so I want to use [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/). After following the [Django rest framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) how would you configure the api and interact with it to reset a user's password?

I know Django exposes [these paths](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views)

```
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

Note I'm not using BasicAuthentication, I'm using SessionAuthentication. What http requests should a mobile client make?

Answer (score -6):

To use the Django built in Auth flows using SessionAuthentication you should use a browser. See `Warning: Always use Django's standard login view when creating login pages. This will ensure your login views are properly protected.` http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication

In a phone app you shouldn't have to worry about cross site scripting so it's okay to use token authentication and store the token on the phone.

You'll still want to use `SessionAuthentication` for Django-Rest-Framework's browsable api. Remember to force `HttpOnly` cookies and disable the browsable api in production. You can later build a Single Page Application that relies on the same approach as the mobile app but ensure any tokens are stored as secure cookies.

For reset password flow in drf try https://github.com/anx-ckreuzberger/django-rest-passwordreset